# __CUDA_ARCH__ flag with Thrust execution policy

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I have a `__host__ __device__` function which is a wrapper that calls into "sort" function of the thrust library. Inside this wrapper, I am using the `__CUDA_ARCH__` flag to set the execution policy to "thrust::device" when called from host and "thrust::seq" when called from device. The following piece of code generates a runtime error -

```
#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
    thrust::stable_sort(thrust::device, data, data + num, customGreater<T>());
#else
    thrust::stable_sort(thrust::seq, data, data + num, customGreater<T>());
#endif
```

The error is-

Unexpected Standard exception:
What() is:merge_sort: failed on 2nd step: invalid device function

As per my understanding, **CUDA_ARCH** can be used for conditional compilation. I request for help in understanding why this error is thrown.

Comment: I am running this on a Titan Xp and compiled with sm_61. I see this problem specifically with this call to thrust. Using __CUDA_ARCH__ anywhere else in the program seems to work as expected. If I comment #ifndef / #else above and just use thrust::device, it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are stepping on [this issue](https://github.com/NVlabs/cub/issues/30).  In a nutshell, [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust) uses [CUB](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/) functionality under the hood for certain algorithms (including sort). Your use of `__CUDA_ARCH__` macro in your code, which wraps around thrust algorithm calls that use CUB, is interfering with CUB code that expects to be able to use this macro for all paths.

A possible workaround is to do "your own dispatch":

```
$ cat t142.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>


template <typename T>
struct customGreater {
__host__ __device__ bool operator()(T &t1, T &t2){
   return (t1 > t2);}
};

template <typename T>
__host__ __device__
void my_sort_wrapper(T *data, size_t num){
    int hostdev = 0;  // 0=device code
#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
    hostdev = 1;  // 1=host code
#endif
    if (hostdev == 0) thrust::stable_sort(thrust::seq, data, data + num, customGreater<T>());
    else thrust::stable_sort(thrust::device, data, data + num, customGreater<T>());

}

template <typename T>
__global__ void my_dev_sort(T *data, size_t num){
  my_sort_wrapper(data, num);
}
typedef int mytype;
const size_t sz = 10;
int main(){
  mytype *d_data;
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, sz*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMemset(d_data, 0, sz*sizeof(mytype));
  my_sort_wrapper(d_data, sz);
  my_dev_sort<<<1,1>>>(d_data, sz);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc t142.cu -o t142
$ cuda-memcheck ./t142
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

With this realization, the use of the `__CUDA_ARCH__` macro does not perturb the compilation of the thrust algorithms.

Another possible workaround is simply to use `thrust::device` policy for both cases (no dispatch - just the thrust algorithm call).  Except in the case of CUDA Dynamic Parallelism, `thrust::device` will "decay" to `thrust::seq` when used in device code.

I would expect that these suggestions would only be necessary/relevant when the thrust algorithm uses CUB functionality in the underlying implementation.

If you don't like this behavior, you could file a [thrust issue](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, we can't fix this in Thrust. The trouble here is that the NVCC compiler needs to see all `__global__` function template instantiations during host compilation (e.g. when `__CUDA_ARCH__` is not defined), otherwise the kernels will be treated as unused and discarded. See [this CUB GitHub issue](https://github.com/NVlabs/cub/issues/30) for more details.

As Robert suggested, a workaround such as this should be fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

template <typename T>
struct customGreater {
__host__ __device__ bool operator()(T &t1, T &t2){
   return (t1 > t2);}
};

#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__)
  #define DEVICE_COMPILATION 1
#else
  #define DEVICE_COMPILATION 0
#endif

template <typename T>
__host__ __device__
void my_sort(T *data, size_t num){
  if (DEVICE_COMPILATION)
    thrust::stable_sort(thrust::device, data, data + num, customGreater<T>());
  else
    thrust::stable_sort(thrust::seq, data, data + num, customGreater<T>());
}

template <typename T>
__global__ void my_dev_sort(T *data, size_t num){
  my_sort(data, num);
}
typedef int mytype;
const size_t sz = 10;
int main(){
  mytype *d_data;
  cudaMallocManaged(&d_data, sz*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMemset(d_data, 0, sz*sizeof(mytype));
  my_sort(d_data, sz);
  my_dev_sort<<<1,1>>>(d_data, sz);
  cudaFree(d_data);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```